# Java Watson Text to Speech synthesize to speech

Tags: android, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I'm currently attempting to create a text-to-speech app in Android.  The project is all set up and I have successfully imported the Java wrapper.

I am currently unsure whether or not it is possible to synthesize to speech, rather than to audio.

```
InputStream stream = mTTSService.synthesize ("Hello", Voice.EN_ALLISON).execute();
```

I essentially want my app to be able to speak a passed string, rather than save it as an audio file.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel. You might be interested in using the [Android SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk), which includes additional helper classes for Android.

For example, the Android SDK includes a `StreamPlayer` class that can be used to play synthesized audio. This short [snippet](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk#streamplayer) of code from the Android SDK readme shows how to use the `StreamPlayer` class.

The Android SDK also includes an [example application](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk/tree/master/example) that might be helpful.

(Note that you will need *both* SDKs in your project--the Android SDK does not duplicate any of the Java SDK's functionality.)